# my functions in constructor are not reachable

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new to reactjs and jsx. I need to use onDragOver and onDragStart functionality of html5 in my react project. So I defined functions as follows in constructor of mycode:

```
 export class Navbar extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super();
    var allowDrop = function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("source", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var src = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("source"));
        var srcParent = src.parentNode;
        var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

        ev.currentTarget.replaceChild(src, tgt);
        srcParent.appendChild(tgt);
    }

}

componentDidMount() {
  }

render() {
    return (
        <ul className="navigation">
            <li id="t1" className="nav-item" onDrop={this.drop(event)} onDragOver={this.allowDrop(event)}><a href="#"
                                                                                                        draggable="true"
                                                                                                        onDragStart={thisdrag(event)}>Greater
                Saint John</a></li>


            <li className="nav-item" id="t2" ondrop={this.drop(event)} onDragOver={this.allowDrop(event)}><a href="#"
                                                                                                        draggable="true"
                                                                                                        onDragStart={this.drag(event)}><span
                className="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;    The Victoria Star</a></li>

        </ul>
     );
   }
   }
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.allowDrop is not a function
```

can anyone help?

Comment: You created a function that's scoped to just the constructor. If you want a class method, put the method in the class, not the constructor.

Comment: @lux thanks for answering when I add my functions directly to the class I get compilation error

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: for instance when I put the follwing directly in class  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("source", ev.target.id);
}  I get expecting newline or semicolon and the error happens between function and drag

Comment: @lux I also tried this :  drag: drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("source", ev.target.id);
} but the same problem

Comment: You're getting errors since that's incorrect syntax for a JS class. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Class method definitions do not need the `function` keyword. Put the method in the class just the same way as `componentDidMount()` and `render()` are. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods

Comment: @devthorne anyway I think your answer fixed my problem if you can add it as an answer I will accept it for other new to jsx developers like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because allowDrop is not visible outside constructor as it is a function expression.

`function allowDrop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
}`

Declare allowDrop as mentioned above and this should solve the problem.
More details on function declaration vs function expression:
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/